# Adding maven dependency fro Jira plugin development

Tags: maven, jira

I am developing a Jira plugin from starter code at https://atlassian_tutorial@bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/jira-scheduled-events.git

I added some third party maven dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

When I started Jira, I faced Jira Locked error. When I removed those maven dependencies and restarted again, everything is normal. Jira is working. Where am I going wrong? Is there any special way to add maven dependencies for Jira plugins?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have not tried [official](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/troubleshooting-jira-startup-failed-error-394464512.html) Atlassian troubleshooting guide, then this is the first thing you should do.

You can try stop Jira, remove these files:

```
$JIRA_HOME/plugins/.bundled_plugins
$JIRA_HOME/plugins/.osgi_plugins
```

and try to start Jira again.
Also ensure Jira has sufficient [memory](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Increasing+JIRA+Memory?_ga=2.44230500.1767514070.1524400759-1855849493.1524400759).